# Maximum number of possible playable songs

Tags: storage, ram, mp3

I have a library of over 100,000 mp3 songs. I have tried and failed to modify an iPod to be able to accommodate this number, but a friend recently suggested I store them on a 1TB micro SD card, and use an Android device to play them. Is this possible? I am afraid that the limited RAM could be a potential problem in traversing through this vast number of files.
Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Let's simplify the question. I have 300 GB of music that I want to have all on one device which I can use like an MP3 player. How can this be done?

Comment: First of all, I doubt a 1TB microSD card exists.

Comment: @iBug https://www.google.com/search?q=1TB+micro+SD+card&oq=1TB+micro+SD+card

Comment: Which MP3 player do you use?

Comment: No phone currently reads sd more than 256GB. You gotta be on a computer

Comment: @ThallyAce What does this limit depend upon, if I may?

Comment: It depends on the person who designed file system access protocol. The software designer. It doesn't depend on RAM, CPU speed, or even the ROM you install on the device. Even if you find alternative software to load on your phone as an operating system, be sure this is not gonna change at all.

Comment: @ThallyAce Do we know when support for 512 GB cards will happen...approximately?

Comment: Not really but at the rate technology is moving at, I'm sure they gonna be soon in mainstream phones like Google, BlackBerry, Samsung and IPhone since these companies have a trend to compete for superiority

Comment: @ThallyAce If conputers can manage big cards while phones cannot, I'm temped to point to the kernel as the culprit, you know.